# Running puppet apply using master for dependencies

Tags: testing, vagrant, puppet

I wish to be able to modify modules locally before commit to source control.
I believe I need to use `puppet apply`.
I create a `init.pp` test file including my module and add `--modulepath` directing to my module directory.
My problem is that all my dependencies exists on the puppet master and I don't want to download all dependencies. I want to have the version exists on the master.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I would split my tree into environments: test and productions, or something similar.

In my case I a more "complex" but smart method!
I do have a git repo, and i do have it in 2 places

> 1. /etc/puppet
> 2. /home/myuser/puppet-main

Both places are an environment,

**Puppet.conf:**

```
[main]
    logdir = /var/log/puppet
    rundir = /var/run/puppet
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl
    factpath = $vardir/lib/facter
    environmentpath = $confdir/environments
    basemodulepath = /usr/share/puppet/modules
    environment_timeout = 30s
```

The /etc/puppet directory tree:

```
.
./environments
./environments/example_env
./environments/example_env/modules
./environments/example_env/manifests
./environments/billias
./environments/production
./environments/production/modules
./environments/production/manifests
./environments/production/hieradata
./modules
./manifests
```

Then my /etc/puppet/environments/production/environment.conf

```
environment_timeout = 30s
modulepath = modules/platform:modules/config:modules/main:$basemodulepath
```

The last but not least my /etc/puppet/environments/billias (my personal env) has symlink to the directories/files of production, but the one copied into my personal home dir:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   52 Dec 22 19:04 environment.conf -> /etc/puppet/environments/production/environment.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   60 Nov 28 22:31 hieradata -> /home/billias/puppet-main/environments/production/hieradata/
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   60 Nov 28 22:31 manifests -> /home/billias/puppet-main/environments/production/manifests/
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   58 Nov 28 22:31 modules -> /home/billias/puppet-main/environments/production/modules/
```

Last but not least, this way i can write code on my **/home/billias/puppet-main/environments/production/** and commit it on my git after i finish with it...

i can test the code before pushing it by:
**puppet agent -t --environment=billias**

If you have questions, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: you can also use environments with manifest and modulepath for each one separated inside the puppetmaster.conf... but it is always what you like to do.

Comment: I dont really see how you resolve the dependencies using the puppet muster..... I see all dependencies are local on your machine

Comment: you can use the same tree on the remote location, by setting up environments, and the command i mentioned should run on the client side! to test the new code before committing it.

In other words, you do setup multiple envs on the puppet master, and you run the puppet agent with different environment, which has the changes compared to your production...

this is the best way to solve depedencie

Comment: @VassilisAretakis in other words - do the testing **on the master**, but in a separate environment, where the master can use the manifests etc. before committing.

Comment: Felix, something like that... you modify the recipes on the master under separate environment and execute them from your agents (clients systems)
That way you do test against your full recipe tree (and check for other issues too....) Do not forget also the option **--noop**

Comment: @VassilisAretakis You assume I have access to the master, but thats not the case. In my case master is owned by DevOps team not my team. and again in your suggestion any developer trying to use dev env is affected by my changes, which is the same like commit the changes...

Comment: In that case, your DevOps team should prepare this... cause it will help you develop recipes for the servers.

Comment: @VassilisAretakis No DevOps in the world will create environment for each developer in the company. specially not in company of over 500 developers.

Comment: I'm working in a company of this size, and we do have environments for each user who has access to these servers.

But our devs also, doesn't have to perform complex stuff (only config changes for our Java microservices.

Comment: @VassilisAretakis if so I apologies for my previous replay. but in my case developers creates their modules for each service include installing configuring and deploying (Im not sure if that what you call complex)

Comment: @NoamShaish for that, we do it also through Devops, and we do have a simplified way to introduce services. We do have an procedure from the naming of the service to the location etc... So the DevOps and devs knows this and follows it.

For us introducing a new service is 2 hiera records in the end, but we have organised.

I understand your difficulties/issues and i empathise, for that. Technically even if you try the manifests locally, you might break something on production. but puppet apply if you keep a structure of module/manifest/init.pp should work.